# Two samba servers and UID,GID mappings across them

Tags: ldap, samba

I have a samba server and just installed the second one to configure a reserve file server.

It all went well and both of them successfully are on *Active Directory* domain (actually *SAMBA 4*)

the problem is that on the **server 2** user shares messed with wrong uid/gids.

and if I `id user1` on **server 1** I get `2010`
but but I run `id user1` on **server 2** I get `2031`

They use 99% identical `smb.conf`

and they have: `passdb backend = tdbsam`

I have found out that in order to achieve equal UID/GID's I would need to use `ldapsam`
but I don't know how to do it.

Do I need to first export from tdbsam and then install ldap server on **server 1** export to that ldap server?

and then  set `passdb backend` to `ldapsam` on both?

Answer (score 1):

You could export samba's users on the first server an import them on the next with pdbedit:

```
pdbedit -e tdbsam:/tmp/tdbsam.bak
```

and scp or rsync the file to the second server and on the second server:

```
pdbedit -i tdbsam:/tmp/tdbsam.bak
```

or import them from tdbsam (the local file) to ldapsam:

```
pdbedit -i tdbsam:/tmp/tdbsam.bak -e ldapsam:ldap://127.0.0.1
```

Edit: 
I just saw this is an onl question... well if somebody still needs this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Almost one year have passed and I am going to test soon. Hopefully I will mark it as accepted.